# How to create new project from GIT repo using Eclipse EGit

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I have added a new GIT repo (private github repo) to Eclipse EGit repo explorer. In the working directory, our team has many projects - some python, some C++, some PHP - they are in different sub-directories. I choose a dir with python project and from the context menu I select "Import" then complete the steps with "New Project Wizard". I choose new "PyDev" project and end up with new project that is empty - only Eclipse files like the .project inside.

I want to create a new python project with the contents of ~/git/repo - I don't want external other copy of the tree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could follow [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html#adding-a-new-project-to-a-git-repository), and share your project.

[image: Create Egit repo]

That would create a local Git repo, to which you can add your private GitHub repo as a remote.
See also "[Pushing a Local Repository to GitHub](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Remote#Pushing_a_Local_Repository_to_GitHub) ".

> Select your new Eclipse project and click `"Team" > "Push To"` and enter `"Your GitHub Clone URL"` and your GitHub password (with the free GitHub accounts, do not enter a password but leave blank), leave the user as "git"

[image: push to GitHub repo]

Comment: Thank you VonC! Creating a project in the ~/git/repo-dir/project-sub-dir then Team -> Share Project -> git did it for me.